# Java sets and SQL querys

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a Set  areas , I also have a sql query where area has to be used. Whats the easiest way use all the areas in the list in the query ?

ps I know query should look something like like

```
AND area IN('%New york%','%Las vegas%')
```

Comment: Why for each element you use `%` is that required, what are you using jdbc or JPA spring data, or what ...???

Comment: This looks fine. What is the issue ? `AND area IN ('New york','Las vegas') `

Comment: `AND (area LIKE = '%New york%' OR area LIKE = '%Las vegas%')`

Comment: @YCF_L  Im using namedjdbc pararamters and have varied number of elements on different days for each ares

Comment: @Javaman you can use `areas.replaceAll(r -> r.replaceFirst(".*", "%$0%"));` this will convert your list to `[%New york%, %Las vegas%]` then pass your list as parameter

Comment: @YCF_L this wont work as its actually Set<String> sorry for not being clearer

Comment: @Javaman sorry I thought a List in this case you can use `areas = areas.stream().map(r -> r.replaceFirst(".*", "%$0%")).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: ANy way to do it for a set ??

Comment: What did you mean, the solution work for a Set..

Comment: @YCF_L The only problem i'm having is that the [ are in string

Comment: can you please show use your code? I don't understand how you use my code

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
AND area in ('New york','Las vegas')
```

OR

```
AND  (area like'%New york%' or area like'%Las vegas%')
```

Answer (score 0):

do you really need %? this means that you will accept any other value than 'New york' or 'Las vegas'.

-Using hibernate you can use Restriction.in("area", areaSet); 
or using HQLwhere name in (:names)

-by hand you can use String sql="select * from area where name in ("StringUtils.join(set, ',')+")"; or you can use streams and set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(','))

Comment: not really as the ares are taken from another table in my sql so its juts a bout turning the set in to a list of strings

Comment: ok I have edited, I suppose that what you want is StringUtils.join(set, ',') or eventually you can use streams and set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(','))